# How do I edit text in Cyrillic / Russian on OpenBSD?

Tags: emacs, openbsd, character-encoding

I'm trying to make it possible to easily edit text in Cyrillic / Russian on a remote OpenBSD 5.2 amd64.

I'm using [`emacs-21.4p18-no_x11`](http://ports.su/editors/emacs21,no_x11,-main), which doesn't show any Cyrillic characters whatsoever when I try opening up a file with a `windows-1251` encoding (instead showing question marks and sometimes even randomly mangling the file when a save is attempted), unless I start it as `env LANG=bg_BG.CP1251 emacs` (for some reason, there's no `ru_RU.CP1251` in [`/usr/share/locale/`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/share/locale/)) and PuTTY to `Win1251 (Cyrillic)`; however, this only works in displaying the characters, not for typing any characters -- switching the local keyboard to Russian and typing into emacs causes various random internal commands to be executed, even though quitting emacs and using [`cat(1)`](http://mdoc.su/o/cat.1) works without any issues for Russian input (which could then be opened up in emacs and copy-pasted from the temp file to the real one, which is very cumbersome and unproductive).

I've also tried [`mg(1)`](http://bxr.su/OpenBSD/usr.bin/mg/tutorial), but it shows up Russian characters as `\315` etc, and doesn't let you type in Russian, either.

- If the files I'm editing are `nginx.conf`, is there a way to automatically specify the encoding for emacs?  All the [File Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html) examples appear to start with a `mode`, but there's no mode for `nginx.conf`.
- How do I make emacs / mg load files in either `windows-1251` or `koi8-r`, and show them in `UTF-8`?
- How do I make emacs / mg accept Cyrillic input?

Answer (score -1):

You can set the language environment to Russian.

```
M-x set-language-environment
```

If you than open your file it should be readable.